# No qemu-kvm console output when I run kvm inside bash script

Tags: bash, console, qemu, kvm

I'm running kvm image from command line;

```
$ qemu-kvm -name openSUSE -M pc -m 2048 -drive file=hda -nographic
```

And I configured console=ttyS0 inside kvm image, so the kvm's console output is displayed in the host terminal output.

But when I try the same command in bash script, nothing displayed!
Can you please let me know how to capture kvm's console output from basn script?

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the bash script?  Sounds like something might not be redirected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you script start with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And set the full path to you disk file, for example

```
#!/bin/bash
qemu-kvm -name openSUSE -M pc -m 2048 -drive file=/foo/hda -nographic
```

Then set execution permission with

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

now try with

```
./script.sh
```

Cheers